# Calculate Probit Estimates for samples via Loop

Tags: r, loops, glm, binomial-coefficients

I have a sample dataset that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
test_df <- structure(list(test = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), test2 = c(34.6, 
53.3, 53.9, 71.5, 40.6, 15.3, 34, 62.7, 5.7, 85.2, 21.3, 53.9, 
13.7, 32.5, 62.1, 25.6, 63.5, 48.6, 93.8, 85.7, 37.1, 31.4, 82.8, 
45.2, 31.6, 9.8, 6.5, 68.9, 66.8, 90.4, 30.2, 93.3, 20.2, 79.2, 
22.5, 3.1, 86.2, 68.5, 94.2, 67.6, 84.3, 36.2, 39.2, 56.8, 9.5, 
19.4, 58.8, 75.1, 86.7, 37.2, 79.9, 5.8, 62.3, 35.7, 58.8, 91.4, 
20, 36.9, 67.1, 76.8, 52.2, 82.8, 52.7, 50.2, 42, 36.2, 12.4, 
29.8, 27.7, 77, 77.8, 14.4, 51.6, 59.7, 50.6, 38.6, 42.6, 1.2, 
91.9, 8, 50.7, 82, 59.8, 42.4, 55.9, 78.9, 16.8, 97, 47.4, 93, 
90.1, 75.1, 67.7, 64.8, 7.3, 42.4, 53.1, 94.3, 71.2, 72.4, 34.6, 
53.3, 53.9, 71.5, 40.6, 15.3, 34, 62.7, 5.7, 85.2, 21.3, 53.9, 
13.7, 32.5, 62.1, 25.6, 63.5, 48.6, 93.8, 85.7, 37.1, 31.4, 82.8, 
45.2, 31.6, 9.8, 6.5, 68.9, 66.8, 90.4, 30.2, 93.3, 20.2, 79.2, 
22.5, 3.1, 86.2, 68.5, 94.2, 67.6, 84.3, 36.2, 39.2, 56.8, 9.5, 
19.4, 58.8, 75.1, 86.7, 37.2, 79.9, 5.8, 62.3, 35.7, 58.8, 91.4, 
20, 36.9, 67.1, 76.8, 52.2, 82.8, 52.7, 50.2, 42, 36.2, 12.4, 
29.8, 27.7, 77, 77.8, 14.4, 51.6, 59.7, 50.6, 38.6, 42.6, 1.2, 
91.9, 8, 50.7, 82, 59.8, 42.4, 55.9, 78.9, 16.8, 97, 47.4, 93, 
90.1, 75.1, 67.7, 64.8, 7.3, 42.4, 53.1, 94.3, 71.2, 72.4), test3 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -200L
))
```

I am now trying to calculate Probit-Estimates via `glm`. I want to calculate the same model a few times always choosing a different sample from the dataset based on `test3`. So far I got

```
id <- unique(test_df$test3)
for (i in 1:5)
{
  random[i] <- sample(id,3)
  data[i] <- test_df %>% filter(id %in% random[i])
  model <- glm(test~test2+test3,family = binomial(link = "probit"),data = data[i])
  res <- summary(model)
  results[i] <- res$coefficients
}
```

However, this returns

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 200 or 1, not size 10.
ℹ Input `..1` is `id %in% random[i]`.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so that in the end I get 5 different coefficients for every variable? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible ... what are `random` and `data` initialized to? If they were empty lists you could use double-bracket indexing (`random[[i]]`, etc.) and your code would probably work until you got to the `glm` statement, at which point your `glm` would probably crash for the reason suggested by @IRTFM ...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)


id <- unique(test_df$test3)

results <- tibble(i=NA, results=NA)

for (i in 1:5)
{ 

  random <- sample(id, 3)

  
  data <- test_df %>% filter(test3 %in% random)
  model <- glm(test~test2+test3,family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = data)
  
  res <- tibble(i=i, results=tidy(model))
  
  results <- bind_rows(results, res)
  
}
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

results
#> # A tibble: 16 x 2
#>        i results$term $estimate  $std.error $statistic $p.value
#>    <int> <chr>            <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1    NA <NA>         NA           NA        NA        NA      
#>  2     1 (Intercept)  -2.95e+ 1 29910.       -9.88e- 4  0.999  
#>  3     1 test2         2.37e- 3   282.        8.41e- 6  1.00   
#>  4     1 test3         4.54e+ 0  4455.        1.02e- 3  0.999  
#>  5     2 (Intercept)  -6.85e+ 0 15834.       -4.32e- 4  1.00   
#>  6     2 test2        -3.83e-17   211.       -1.82e-19  1      
#>  7     2 test3        -5.52e-16  1732.       -3.19e-19  1      
#>  8     3 (Intercept)  -1.34e+ 0     0.610    -2.20e+ 0  0.0277 
#>  9     3 test2        -5.49e- 3     0.00704  -7.80e- 1  0.436  
#> 10     3 test3         2.20e- 1     0.0834    2.64e+ 0  0.00827
#> 11     4 (Intercept)  -6.85e+ 0 15061.       -4.55e- 4  1.00   
#> 12     4 test2        -2.94e-18   224.       -1.32e-20  1      
#> 13     4 test3         4.95e-16  1821.        2.72e-19  1      
#> 14     5 (Intercept)  -3.52e- 1     0.585    -6.01e- 1  0.548  
#> 15     5 test2        -1.68e- 3     0.00678  -2.48e- 1  0.804  
#> 16     5 test3         2.52e- 1     0.114     2.21e+ 0  0.0272
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Normally loops that repeat analytic processes fail because the inner logic does not have indexing on the LHS of assignments. Here it fails because of those indices which are not initialized or might have been but perhaps were indexed improperly: Try this modification:

```
id <- unique(test_df$test3); results <- list()
for (i in 1:5)
{
    random <- sample(id,3)
    data1 <- test_df %>% filter(test3 %in% random) #note the need to use a column name
    model <- glm(test~test2+test3,family = binomial(link = "probit"),data = data1)
    res <- summary(model)
    results[[i]] <- res$coefficients # note need to use `[[` rather than `[`
}

str(results)
List of 5
 $ : num [1:3, 1:4] 6.85 8.02e-12 5.50e-10 2.18e+04 2.37e+02 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "test2" "test3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
 $ : num [1:3, 1:4] 3.35e+01 -3.41e-04 -1.34e+01 2.49e+04 1.73e+02 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "test2" "test3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
 $ : num [1:3, 1:4] -0.414455 -0.000279 -0.000755 0.59573 0.006827 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "test2" "test3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
 $ : num [1:3, 1:4] -1.54385 -0.00582 0.24211 0.7596 0.00707 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "test2" "test3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
 $ : num [1:3, 1:4] -0.62463 0.00318 0.23255 0.48835 0.00699 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "test2" "test3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
```